# in Model.save(), how can i check if a ImageField has changed?

Tags: django

in Model.save(), how can i check if a ImageField has changed?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (img is changed):
            #resize new img 
        else:
            #do nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the `md5` of old `img` and new `img`

```
if md5(old_img) != md5(new_img):
    # do something
```